# Unable To Find API Call

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I am attempting to find the API called by this site to retrieve the data used to populate the graph.

Site: https://www.cargurus.com/Cars/price-trends/

I have tried using the network tab on the chrome developer tools, but when I refresh the page I am unable to find a call that returns the relevant data.

Answer (score 0):

Its working as server-side rendering. The page rendered on the backend, and the final page is sent to you. This means data is not shared. To fetch the data, you could write a crawler and extract it element by element from the HTML, but this method is not very reliable.